# How to groupby in Python by character?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe like this:

```
Name       Gender
Leo         Male
Lilly       Female
Angela      Female
Donald      Male
```

I want to see the most common character in name by each gender.

So i want to groupby character. Something like this: (this code is wrong, just an example of what i want)

`df.groupby('NameCharacter')['gender'].value_counts()`

Expected output is like this (not in this format, but just to give you an idea about the expected information, i want):

```
"L" found 2 times, 1 times in female and 1 time in male
"l" found 4 time, 3 times in female and 1 times in male
"e" found 2 times, 1 time in female and 1 time in male
```

etcc.....

I did this using a forloop, but it takes a lot of time and complex.

Comment: please share your for loop code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution that uses Pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexing to separate the male and female names, joins them into a string, and then [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on the string of names to get a count of the characters.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Leo', 'Lily', 'Angela'], 'Gender':['Male', 'Female', 'Female']})

male_name_string = ''.join(df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'Male', 'Name'])
female_name_string = ''.join(df.loc[df['Gender'] == 'Female', 'Name'])

male_char_count = Counter(male_name_string)
female_char_count = Counter(female_name_string)

unique_char = set(list(male_char_count.keys()) + list(female_char_count.keys()))
for c in unique_char:
    print(f'{c} found {female_char_count[c]} times in female and {male_char_count[c]} times in male')
```

Output:

```
n found 1 times in female and 0 times in male
e found 1 times in female and 1 times in male
g found 1 times in female and 0 times in male
A found 1 times in female and 0 times in male
a found 1 times in female and 0 times in male
L found 1 times in female and 1 times in male
o found 0 times in female and 1 times in male
l found 2 times in female and 0 times in male
y found 1 times in female and 0 times in male
i found 1 times in female and 0 times in male
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

x = df.groupby('Gender')
for key, item in x:
    d = x.get_group(key)['Name'].tolist()
    d = ''.join(d)

    chars = np.unique(list(d))
    for c in chars:
        print(c,' appeared ',d.count(c),'times in ',key)
```

Output: Not exactly in the format you've asked but gives what you need.

```
A  appeared  1 times in  Female
L  appeared  1 times in  Female
a  appeared  1 times in  Female
e  appeared  1 times in  Female
g  appeared  1 times in  Female
i  appeared  1 times in  Female
l  appeared  3 times in  Female
n  appeared  1 times in  Female
y  appeared  1 times in  Female
D  appeared  1 times in  Male
L  appeared  1 times in  Male
a  appeared  1 times in  Male
d  appeared  1 times in  Male
e  appeared  1 times in  Male
l  appeared  1 times in  Male
n  appeared  1 times in  Male
o  appeared  2 times in  Male
```

Comment: Amazed as you, when I saw it for the first time.